# Print all elements in an array in AWK

Tags: arrays, awk, bioinformatics

I want to loop through all elements in an array in awk and print. The values are sourced from the file below:

```
Ala     A       Alanine
Arg     R       Arginine
Asn     N       Asparagine
Asp     D       Aspartic acid
Cys     C       Cysteine
Gln     Q       Glutamine
Glu     E       Glutamic acid
Gly     G       Glycine
His     H       Histidine
Ile     I       Isoleucine
Leu     L       Leucine
Lys     K       Lysine
Met     M       Methionine
Phe     F       Phenylalanine
Pro     P       Proline
Pyl     O       Pyrrolysine
Ser     S       Serine
Sec     U       Selenocysteine
Thr     T       Threonine
Trp     W       Tryptophan
Tyr     Y       Tyrosine
Val     V       Valine
Asx     B       Aspartic acid or Asparagine
Glx     Z       Glutamic acid or Glutamine
Xaa     X       Any amino acid
Xle     J       Leucine or Isoleucine
TERM    TERM    termination codon
```

I have tried this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}{if (FNR==NR) {codes[$1]=$2;} else{next}}END{for (key in codes);{print key,codes[key],length(codes)}}' $input1 $input2
```

And the output is always `Cys   C   27` and when I replace `codes[$1]=$2` for `codes[$2]=$1` I get `M   Met 27`.

How can I make my code print out all the values sequentially? I don't understand why my code selectively prints out just one element when I can tell the array length is 27 as expected. (To keep my code minimal I have excluded code within `else{next}` - Otherwise I just want to print all elements from array `codes` while retaining the `else{***}` command)

According to [How to view all the content in an awk array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183279/how-to-view-all-the-content-in-an-awk-array), The syntax above should work. I tried it here `echo -e "1 2\n3 4\n5 6" | awk '{my_dict[$1] = $2};END {for(key in my_dict) print key " : " my_dict[key],": "length(my_dict)}'` and that worked well.

Comment: You was passing only 1 file(in your initial question later you changed to 2 files) into your awk and now I could see you are passing 2 files into awk program. Could you please do let me know if you simply want to print array items from 1 file? If this is the case then we need not to use 2nd file.

Comment: Your edit fails to explain what the second file contains. Anyway, your code simply ignores the second file entirely.

Comment: I want to use the first input file `$input1` to build an awk array. Then I will use the array in to gsub a field in the file2.`gsub(key, codes[key], $3)` . My puzzle is with the Array `codes` which seems not to let me loop through all of its 27 elements. I c an provide the links to the second file/ all my AWK code if needed

Comment: Also, your code does not do at all what you say it does. Please [edit] to provide a [mre].

Comment: Your code assumes tab-separated columns, but your sample data seems to have spaces between columns. Take out the `FS="\t"` if you really want to process space-separated data. (Even then, your code handles only two columns, whereas your data has three.)

Comment: It is a tab-separated txt file. The reason I am using `FS="\t"`

Answer (score 8):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
  codes[$1]=$2
}
END{
  for(key in codes){
     print key,codes[key],length(codes)
  }
}' Input_file
```

Will add detailed explanation and OP's misses too in few mins.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                    ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS="\t"             ##Setting FS and OFS as TAB here.
}
{
  codes[$1]=$2            ##Creating array codes with index of 1st field and value of 2nd field
}
END{                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in codes){      ##Traversing through codes array here.
     print key,codes[key],length(codes)  ##Printing index and value of current item along with total length of codes.
  }
}' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Made some edits. Ideally, two input files will be given. The part that failed read the first file when `FNR==NR`.

Comment: @Kibet, yeah I have commented under your question, kindly do provide info on that so that I could try to help you on same, thank you.

Comment: Resolved...It was just a matter of `;` and spaces

Comment: @Kibet, Good to hear that, could you please post your answer in here, that will be helpful for future users, please do add the answer, thank you.

Comment: Solution `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}{if (FNR==NR) {codes[$1]=$2;} else{next}}END{for (key in codes){print key,codes[key],length(codes)}}'` $input1 $input2

Comment: @Kibet, sure, kindly add it as an answer so that future users can get benifit

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused what you are after, but to print the codes sequentially, with the no., (ignoring the name), you can do:

```
awk '{seq[++n]=$2; codes[$2]=$1} 
    END{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s\t%s\t%d\n", codes[seq[i]], seq[i], i}' file
```

Which uses two arrays to coordinate the sequence number with the single letter in the `seq` array and then the letter to the code in the `codes` array.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '{seq[++n]=$2; codes[$2]=$1} 
    END{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s\t%s\t%d\n", codes[seq[i]], seq[i], i}' file
Ala     A       1
Arg     R       2
Asn     N       3
Asp     D       4
Cys     C       5
Gln     Q       6
Glu     E       7
Gly     G       8
His     H       9
Ile     I       10
Leu     L       11
Lys     K       12
Met     M       13
Phe     F       14
Pro     P       15
Pyl     O       16
Ser     S       17
Sec     U       18
Thr     T       19
Trp     W       20
Tyr     Y       21
Val     V       22
Asx     B       23
Glx     Z       24
Xaa     X       25
Xle     J       26
TERM    TERM    27
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: The error was brought about by the introduction of `;` here: `END{for (key in codes);{print key,codes[key],length(codes)}}`.
Solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}{if (FNR==NR) {codes[$1]=$2;} else{next}}END{for (key in codes){print key,codes[key],length(codes)}}' $input1 $input2
```